# Multiply two large numbers in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

```
public long Fib(int a1, int a2, int i){
    if(i==1){            
        return a1;
    }else if(i==2){            
        return a2;
    }else{
        long l1 = Fib(a1, a2, i-1);
        long l2 = Fib(a1, a2, i-2);

        long val = l2 + (l1*l1);
        return val;
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to find a *Modified Fibonacci of function* of **t(i+2) = t(i) + t(i+1)^2** where t(i) is the answer when we find ith iterartion. 
But when I find t(10), it gives a separate answer. 
But I got correct answers till t(9). I tried BigInteger method but it gives errors.

Comment: What is `t(10)` ?  What does the function `t()` have to do with `Fib()` ?

Comment: post the code with the biginteger too please

Comment: You will need `BigInteger`.  If you get errors and you can't figure out why, post a question about that and show us the code you've tried.

Comment: What does `Fib(3, 5, 0)` return? Or, put differently: does it return at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your code a little if you want to use `BigInteger`s. Something like:

```
public class ModifiedFib
{
    static BigInteger Fib(int a1, int a2, int i)
    {
        if (i <= 0)
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        else if (i == 1)
            return BigInteger.valueOf(a1);
        else if (i == 2)
            return BigInteger.valueOf(a2);
        else
        {
            BigInteger b1 = Fib(a1, a2, i - 1);
            BigInteger b2 = Fib(a1, a2, i - 2);

            return b1.multiply(b1).add(b2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i <= 11; i++)
            System.out.println("i = " + i + ": " + Fib(0, 1, i));
    }
}
```

I added a check for `i <= 0` and return `ZERO` in that case. I don't know what inputs you have, but in `main()`, I have a simple loop demo-ing the function.

Output:

```
i = -1: 0
i = 0: 0
i = 1: 0
i = 2: 1
i = 3: 1
i = 4: 2
i = 5: 5
i = 6: 27
i = 7: 734
i = 8: 538783
i = 9: 290287121823
i = 10: 84266613096281243382112
i = 11: 7100862082718357559748563880517486086728702367
```

Comment: I had used BigInteger and it worked. Thank you for the help..